# Search content of files inside .7z archive on Mac?

Tags: 7-zip

Hello I have a fairly large .7z archive (~10GB) that contains dozens of .txt files, of which each one contains tens of millions of email address and password pairs.

Is there any quick way to look up entry (e.g: my email) within this .7z archive without extracting it? I'm using Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid unless you have used 0% compression algorithms(meaning you have archived them just for storage) on those files, there is no other way than checking the `.txt` files after you decompress it or use/make some software that can do it for you.

I hope you have a good `processor` and `RAM` because it will take fairly long time if you have implemented good compression algorithms while archiving those `.txt` files

Answer (score 1):

You can't deal with the 7zip directly from the Finder, though tools like [Better Zip](https://macitbetter.com) can see inside without extracting, they cannot search within each text file.

Instead, you could make a read-only compressed Disk Image that would be mountable & searchable - encrypted if required.

It used to be a one-step process but is now a 2-step.

From Disk Utility, File > Blank Image or Image from Folder.
Give it a title; you can leave the other settings below at default for now.
Create a volume large enough to contain the uncompressed data for now.

Once complete, you can then use Images > Convert... to change it to a compressed image. This will make it read-only. At this point you can add encryption, if needed.

The resulting image will be searchable using Spotlight, if you allow it, or something like [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12), once mounted.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way to do this, at least on linux. The first answer is wrong. If 7za binary functions the same way in MacOS then this should work there as well

```
7za -so <filename.7z> | grep "<word>"
```